# How to add programatically rows in a gridview (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this ASPX code:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Eliminar">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Eliminar_BTN__" runat="server" Text="" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Editar">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button ID="Editar_BTN__" runat="server" Text="" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WI">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="WI_DDL__" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ITEM">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ITEM_DDL__" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="L" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="M" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="X" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="J" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="V" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="S" />
            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="D" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

What I want to do is to have a button that when I click on it, I add a row to this gridview, the problem is that the gridview has 2 templatefield columns and I don't know how to do it.

Can someone throw some light on this?

Thanks!

Comment: Add a blank row to the data source you are binding to the GridView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rick is correct; you need to add to the data source. This is a similar example - [Dropdownlist in Gridview value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22826340/dropdownlist-in-gridview-value/22827108#22827108)